# Whats the difference between amplification and gain in a BJT?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, gain

Considering the 3 basic BJT amplifier configurations

[image]

For example

consider CB config,

we have a high Voltage gain but the input resistance is low, so there is no effective transfer of voltage Vsupply to BJT.

If we needed to amplify the current, since CB config has low input resistance, we have an ideal transfer of input current but the current gain is terrible (~1)

How do we qualify amplification then?i mean what is it that the CB amplifier amplifying here.please help me understand the difference between gain and amplification.

Comment: CB is clearly amplifying voltage the gain being the **ratio** of output to input

Comment: Consider a voltage source connected to two resistors in series, most of the voltage is across the HIGH impedance resistor. What i meant by transfer of input voltage Vsupply is if it had high input impedance (ideal infinite) the input voltage would have been properly applied to the input terminals of BJT but this is not the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current through a BJT is controlled by the base-emitter voltage VBE, it depends exponentially on that voltage. From this point of view the BJT is a voltage-controlled device.

The way a BJT works makes it necessary to also have a small current through the base. This base current is only a small fraction of the collector current. The ratio between these currents can be used to define a current gain and it is possible to regard the BJT as a current-controlled device.

So we have two ways to deal with a BJT and depending on the situation one is better than the other.

For a CB circuit we see that input and output current are almost equal and it could be used as a current buffer. Apart from that current gain doesn't help much to gain further insight.

Using the voltage-controlled operation approach, we see that the emitter gives direct access to VBE of the transistor in almost the same we as for the CE configuration, only the sign is different. So a change of the emitter voltage causes a change of VBE. This also changes the current through the transistor  which is then converted into a voltage by Rc. So it is possible to achieve voltage amplification.

However, usually voltage amplifiers with a larger input impedance are wanted and therefore the CE stage is preferred over the CB configuration. This leaves the use as a current buffer like in a cascode circuit.

Comment: Exactly. lets say Vsig is the signal i wanted to amplify but due to low input impedance only a fraction of Vsig i.e. Vinput=[Rin/(Rin + Rsig)]*Vsig is applied to the input port BE where as i intended to amplify Vsig. {Rsig is the source resistance of Vsig source} . this brings to my question CB amplifiers is rendered to be used as a current buffer rather than  an amplifier

Comment: Because of the low input impedance it is not a good voltage amplifier, yet it has the same voltage gain as a CE stage provided that the voltage source is ideal (Rsig =0). Since it is inferior to the CE stage in this regard, its main use will be as a current buffer. I hope this did answer your question.

Comment: @ Mario: so high gain doesnt necessarily mean the signal can be amplified. yes that answers my question

Comment: Actually, it means that the signal can be amplified. But only if the source has small impedance! So the "high gain" is only true under certain conditions and not in general.

Comment: Because of the low input impedance of the CB stage you could use - in addition - a high impedance common collector stage. And as the result - you get the classical differential amplifier (long-tailed pair).

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather confused, but basically the gain of a transistor is just the basic function of the transistor itself.  For a BJT, it is the collector current (at reasonable C-E votlage) divided by the base current.

In this context, amplification is what the overall circuit does.  BJTs can be used in a variety of ways in a circuit.  Different circuits can take the same transistor with the same gain, but end up with different gain (amplification) of the overall circuit.

Also keep in mind that for a circuit, voltage amplification isn't necessarily the objective.  You might want current amplification, or a lower output impedance than input impedance.  The raw current gain of a BJT can be used to achieve all these things, each with different characteristics at the circuit level.

For example, the basic emitter follower has a voltage amplification of nearly 1, but uses the gain of the transistor to get significant current gain.  In a common emitter amplifier, the raw gain of the transistor can be used to get overall voltage gain.

### Added about emitter follower

I see there is some confusion about the emitter follower configuration and how it provides current gain.

Here is a basic emitter follower:

[image]

A rough but still useful first approximation of a BJT is that the B-E voltage is fixed at about 700 mV, and that the collector current is the gain times the base current.  This assumes there is sufficient C-E voltage provided so that the base x gain collector current can actually be drawn.

Using that approximation, the voltage gain (dVout/dVin) of the circuit above is 1 from IN to the load.  However, there is signigicant current gain.

When IN goes up by 1 V, the voltage on the load is increased by 1 V, which means it draws a additional 10 mA.  Let's say the gain of the transistor is 50.  That means for every 1 part of base current, you get 50 parts of collector current, and therefore 51 parts of emitter current.  Of the 10 mA additional E current, 50/51 of that comes from the collector and 1/51 of that from the base.  So for a increase in output current of 10 mA, the increase in input current is only (10 mA)(1 / 51) = 196 µA.

Another way to look at the same thing is as a impedance buffer.  The real output is a 100 Ω load, but at IN is looks like a 5.1 kΩ load.

Of course the rough approximation of the transistor isn't accurate.  No model is.  The B-E junction looks like a diode to the external circuit, so the voltage across it isn't really fixed.  The voltage does vary a little with current.  Or, you can say that small changes in voltage result in a large change in current, just like with a diode.

This circuit therefore has a voltage gain a little less than 1 because the B-E drop goes up a little with increased current.

There are ever more complicated models of transistors that get progressively more accurate, but also progressively harder to use.  Also keep in mind that there are substantial variations between individual transistors, even of the same model.

Take a look at a datasheet, and you'll see that the maximum gain is either not specified, or is many times the minimum gain.  Usually you design BJT circuits so that they work with some minimum gain from the transistor, but continue to work all the way to infinite gain.  This may sound hard, but it's really not.  A variation from 98% to 100% of the emitter current coming from the collector is not a big difference.

Comment: For the basic emitter follower the Input Current can never be properly transferred to the BJT because of high input impedance. Though we have significant current gain, we are unable to supply the bjt with necessary input current right, so how can it be used as for current amplification?

Comment: @Sarat: You just said yourself the input current is low.  The output current is higher, so there is current gain.  In the case of a emitter follower, then current gain is the transistor's gain + 1.

Comment: Olin Lathrop - can you tell me one single application where the emitter follower (watch the term!!) is used "to get significant current gain"?

Comment: @sarat: For a better understanding of the BJT working principle, forget the term "current gain" and rely upon Mario`s excellent answer!

Comment: @LvW: See addition to the answer about emitter follower.  You can argue device physics about whether a BJT is really a voltage controlled device or not, but that just causes confusion, especially for beginners.  Regardless of the internal mechanism, it is perfectly valid and quite useful to look at a BJT as a device that primarily provides current gain.

Comment: Olin Lathrop, I suppose, that you know how the emitter follower´s voltage gain can be found using the transconductance gm - without using the base current at all. Furthermore - is it really a question if (a) the correct view (voltage control) or the false description (current control) will cause confusion on the beginners side? There are many examples and effects which can be explained with voltage control only! So - I doubt if it is really "valid" and quite useful" to use the current control view. One example: How is the saturation region defined (based on voltage or current control) ?